# Yuglify compressor can't find binary from package installed through npm

Tags: django, npm, django-pipeline, yuglify

I have a fresh virtualenv environment and have got the latest django-pipleline.

The JS compression with Closure works perfect, but CSS compression with Yuglify fails, due a node error:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'
PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.closure.ClosureCompressor'
PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor'
```

When I try to collect the static:

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

It says:

```
pipeline.compressors.CompressorError: /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

But I have clearly installed yuglify even as global:

```
sudo npm -g install yuglify

/usr/local/bin/yuglify -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yuglify/bin/yuglify
yuglify@0.1.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yuglify 
├── uglify-js@1.3.4
├── ycssmin@1.0.1
└── nopt@2.1.1
```

Trying to set the biney in settings doesn't help either:

```
PIPELINE_YUGLIFY_BINARY = '/usr/local/bin/yuglify'
```

I still get the same error. Why now such problems with npm?  Is there something I have to setup additionally?

Alternatively is there a way to install yuglify with pip?

Many Thanks,

Comment: Can you try to run this : heroku run /usr/bin/env node

Comment: Thanks for your response. I finally found it. It is an issue with `npm` and how it installs the yuglify package. It is not pretty. You better mention that in the documentation. ;) See my answer.

Comment: When I run heroku run /usr/bin/env node, it starts node terminal. How do I fix it? How do I run Hooman's solution on heroku?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After 3 hours of suffering, I have found the solution.

This is happening because of a misnaming error, if you install from a package manager (npm) your bin may be called nodejs so you just need to symlink it like this:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Now it is working. This didn't happen with the older version, its is something new. But at least it is working again. I hope this helps someone else out there. :)

Comment: Additionally for me, `which node` pointed at `/usr/sbin/node`, not `/usr/bin/node` from the above soft link. Removing the `sbin` version of node brought the yuglify compressor back online.

Comment: Also note that you must install yugliy with the `-g` as you specified above - `sudo npm -g install yuglify`. Without this the binary will not be linked to `/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case both **uglify-js** and **cssmin** were somehow not installed.

So I have re-installed them again by using following command and then it starts working again.

```
sudo npm install -g cssmin uglify-js
```